# Disabling past dates in flowbite datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, flowbite

I am using the following date picker with flowbite and tailwind.

[flowbite datepicker](https://flowbite.com/docs/plugins/datepicker/)

I am using just the calendar and I am trying to disable past dates so that users are unable to click on them.

HTML

```
<div inline-datepicker id="mydatepicker"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
import Datepicker from 'flowbite-datapicker/Datepicker';

const datapicker  = document.getElementById('mydatepicker');

new Datepicker(datapicker, {
todayHighlight: true
});
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Tailwind Datepicker options](https://github.com/OMikkel/tailwind-datepicker-react), you can set the `minDate` option to 'today:

```
new Datepicker(datapicker, {
    todayHighlight: true,
    minDate : new Date()
});
```

---

Small demo demonstrating this
<sub>**Note**, this uses quite an old version since unpkg doesn't have the latest one available</sub>

```js
const datapicker  = document.getElementById('test');

new Datepicker(datapicker, {
    todayHighlight: true,
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.3/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite-datepicker@1.2.2/dist/js/datepicker-full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.3/dist/flowbite.min.css" />

<input id="test" datepicker type="text" placeholder="Select date">
```

Comment: I just worked out how to do this before you posted your answer